# Rewriting the domain extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website with multiple domain extensions:

```
example.com
example.de
example.fr
example.co.uk
```

I would like for people to get redirected to the `.com` domain so that the the urls are rewritten as follows:

```
example.de        -> http://www.example.com/?loc=de
example.fr        -> http://www.example.com/?loc=fr
www.example.co.uk -> http://www.example.com/?loc=uk
```

However, I don't know how to select the domain extension part of the URL `example.(fr)/bla` and rewrite. I realize that I could create special cases for each ex.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.de$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/?loc=de [L,R=301]
```

However I would like to make it so that if I buy more extensions, that I wouldn't need to update the `httpd.conf` file etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple to create a rule that covers several domains.  To achieve what you want, you could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(de|fr|co\.uk)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/?loc=%2 [R]
```

It takes `example.de` and rewrites it as `example.com/~loc=de` as requested, and works also for `.fr`, and `.co.uk`.  However a caveat is that it rewrites the `.co.uk` version as `example.com/~loc=co.uk`, which isn't quite what you want.  It would also need to be modified for new domains.

So, here's a solution that's a little more generic, but should achieve what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.(co\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/?loc=%3 [R]
```

Now a little explanation:

The first `RewriteCond` matches any domain with `example` in it, such as `example.co.uk`, `www.example.de`, `www.example.xxx`, etc.

The second `RewriteCond` makes sure that the HTTP_HOST *isn't* `example.com` or `www.example.com`.

Finally the `RewriteRule` rewrites anything that matches those two rules, and sticks the last part of the domain onto the end as a parameter.

`http://www.example.co.uk/` -> `http://example.com/?loc=uk`

`http://www.example.de/` -> `http://example.com/?loc=de`

`http://www.example.xxx/` -> `http://example.com/?loc=xxx`

`http://www.example.com/` doesn't redirect.

---

Note that in the solutions above, if the user went to `http://www.example.de/some/path/index.php`, the path would not get redirected.  If you want this functionality, then we need to include the path in the redirection:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1?loc=%3 [R]
```